# Powershell Format data of 2 columns into 1

Tags: powershell, citrix

I have the following command which returns an output with 2 different columns

```
Add-PSSnapin Citrix.*

Get-XAApplication -ComputerName "server_name" * | Select-Object DisplayName, ClientFolder

DisplayName     ClientFolder
-------------   ------------
App_A           Folder_1
App_B           Folder_1
App_C           Folder_1
App_D           Folder_2
App_E           Folder_3
App_F           Folder_3
App_G           Folder_4
App_H           Folder_4
App_I           Folder_4
App_J           Folder_4
```

I want to format the data, so that i would get an output like this, in one column instead of 2

The output should remove the duplicates from 2nd column and show as one like below.

Is there any options to do that in PowerShell as i have tried the data formatting but doesn't work

```
Folder_1
App_A
App_B
App_C

Folder_2
App_D

Folder_3
App_E
App_F

Folder_4
App_G
App_H
App_I
App_J
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `Format-List` Cmdlet as follows.

```
Add-PSSnapin Citrix.*

$result = Get-XAApplication -ComputerName "server_name" * | Select-Object DisplayName, ClientFolder;

$result | Format-List -GroupBy ClientFolder -Property DisplayName;
```

This will produce the following output

```
    ClientFolder: Folder_1

DisplayName : App_A
DisplayName : App_B
DisplayName : App_C


    ClientFolder: Folder_2

DisplayName : App_D


    ClientFolder: Folder_3

DisplayName : App_E
DisplayName : App_F


    ClientFolder: Folder_4

DisplayName : App_G
DisplayName : App_H
DisplayName : App_I
DisplayName : App_J
```

Comment: Hi rufer7, thanks for the input but is there any way to get rid of "ClientFolder: " & "DisplayName:" ?

Comment: Hi @MuthukumaranThavarajoo I checked, but did not find a way to get rid of the labels...sorry